# Why can I not add attributes to an attrs object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-attrs

Consider this example:

```
import attrs

@attrs.define(frozen=True)
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        object.__setattr__(self, "field", 1)

A()
```

This fails with an exception:

> AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'field'.

Why can I not add the field to the attrs object? Note of course that this does work when removing the attrs decorator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I noticed that `@attrs.define` has `slots=True` as default argument. Passing `slots=False` resolves this issue. If `slots=True`, then the object will not have a `__dict__` attribute and therefore setting the attribute will fail.